# generate random number from exponential distribution with random right truncation

Tags: probability, exponential-function, random

I need to draw a random number from an exponential distribution (rate $mu$) that is right-truncated with the truncation value coming from a gamma distribution (shape $k$, rate $lambda$).

My naive approach would have been to first draw the truncation value, and then draw from the truncated exponential distribution via Inverse Transform Sampling. However, such draws do not follow the same distribution which I get from simulation results.

The following R code demonstrates that this approach is for some reason not working:

```
    # parameter settings
    k <- 2
    lambda <- 1
    mu <- 0.1
    n <- 1e7 # number of draws

    # draw right truncation values
    trunc_value <- rgamma(n=n, shape=k, rate=lambda)

    # draw from right-truncated exponential via inverse transform sampling
    itexp <- function(u, rate, trunc) { -log(1-u*(1-exp(-trunc*rate)))/rate }
    rtexp <- function(n, rate, trunc) { itexp(runif(n), rate, trunc) }
    x0 <- rtexp(n=n, rate=mu, trunc_value)

    # simulate by drawing from exponential and then discarding values larger than trunc
    x1 <- rexp(n, mu)
    x1 <- x1[x1 < trunc_value]

    # means differ significantly
    mean(x0) # 0.95
    mean(x1) # 1.34
```

Answer (score 1):

I now found a way to draw samples so that they match `x1` as stated in my question.

One can specify the likelihood of the truncated random variable by multiplying the non-truncated probability distribution with the probability of the truncation limit being larger: $$L(x | k,\lambda,\mu) = e^{-\mu x} \cdot P(\text{trunc}\geq x) \\= e^{-\mu x} \cdot (1-F_{\Gamma}(x|k,\lambda)),$$ with $F_\Gamma$ denoting the c.d.f. of the gamma distribution. And then one could generate draws e.g. via slice-sampling.

Here some additional R code, which relies on the slice-sampling method from the diversitree package:

```
    require("diversitree")
    loglik <- function(x) -mu*x + pgamma(x, k, lambda, lower=F, log.p=T)
    x2 <- mcmc(loglik, x.init = k/lambda, nsteps = n/100, 
               w = k/(2*lambda), print.every = n/1000, lower = 0)$pars
    mean(x2) # 1.34
```

Answer (score 0):

`trunc_value` has a mean of about $2$ by construction.

But if you take those which were greater than the original `x1` you will find those used for the the non-rejected `x1` had a mean of about $2.86$.

So your rejection method has biased `trunc_value` upwards and so biased the non-rejected `x1` values upwards.

Comment: Could you elaborate further? How could I then generate random numbers efficiently so that they do follow the distribution of $x1$?

Comment: or were you saying that the simulation $x1$ is flawed, and the $x0$ draws are correct?

Comment: I am saying that your method for `x1` is incorrect.  If you want to reject some of them, then to avoid bias you need to replace the with others for the same `trunc_value`.

Comment: I now found a solution how to draw in order to match `x1`. see the answer which I just posted.